# ¿Cómo saber si una columna contiene un elemento determinado? En R

Tags: r, bucle-for, select

Tengo el siguiente df.

```
set.seed(12)
df<-data.frame(a=sample(c("A","B","C"),10,T),
               b=sample(c(1:100),10,T),
               d=sample(c(50:60),10,T),
               e=sample(c("Z","X","Y"),10,T),
               f=sample(c("A","B","C"),10,T),
               g=sample(c("Z","T","W"),10,T))

df
  a  b  d e f g
  B 82 59 Y A Z
  B 38 60 Z C W
  C 90 56 Z A T
  C 48 54 Y C W
  B 13 58 Z B Z
  A 56 51 Y A W
  A 68 56 Y C W
  B 24 56 X B T
  C 57 59 Y A T
  B 72 53 Y A T
```

Deseo conocer que columnas contienen al elemento `Z`. Es decir, quisiera saber que columnas tienen como elementos a `Z`.

¿Hay alguna función sencilla que permita saber la respuesta?

He realizado el siguiente `for` que me permite saber que columnas tienen el elemento `Z`.

```
t<-c()
for (i in 1:dim(df)[2]) {
  if(sum(df[,i] %in% "Z")!=0){
    sip<-"SI"
  } else{
    sip<-"NO"
  }
  t<-c(t,sip)
}

t
[1] "NO" "NO" "NO" "SI" "NO" "SI"
```

Pero me parece muy tedioso. Quizá haya una forma más sencilla y estoy ignorándola.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo general, en R, las soluciones por medio de ciclos, suelen tener una solución mucho más simple y matricial. En este caso, podrías hacer:

```
ifelse(colSums(df == "Z") > 1,"SI", "NO")

   a    b    d    e    f    g 
"NO" "NO" "NO" "SI" "NO" "SI"
```

La magia aquí está en `df == "Z"` y en que R en este caso transforma automáticamente el `data.frame` en una matriz de caracteres y hace la comparación, luego simplemente sumamos los `TRUE` por columnas y aquellas con al menos una "Z" retornarán un "SI".

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si se desea usar expresiones regulares para buscar caracteres ¿Cómo podría implementarlo? Por lo que veo no aceptaría expresiones regulares su sintaxis.

Comment: La función de igualdad `==` no maneja expresiones regulares.  Si las necesitas sería otro tipo de solución: `ifelse(seq(df) %in% grep("Z", df), "SI", "NO")`

Comment: muchas gracias. Excelente aporte.

Answer (score 3):

una forma muy sencilla de realizarlo es utilizando la función sapply que hace la función de for , es decir revisa en cada columna si se encuentra el valor deseado el código quedaría así

```
set.seed(12)
df<-data.frame(a=sample(c("A","B","C"),10,T),
           b=sample(c(1:100),10,T),
           d=sample(c(50:60),10,T),
           e=sample(c("Z","X","Y"),10,T),
           f=sample(c("A","B","C"),10,T),
           g=sample(c("Z","T","W"),10,T))

 #Este seria el codigo que se utilizaria 
 sapply(df, function(x) any(x %in% "Z"))

   a     b     d     e     f     g 
 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

La función ANY lo que ayuda es para que solo que te el valor de TRUE en caso de que algunos de los datos tenga un valor verdadero

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Y si se desea usar expresiones regulares cambiaría el `x %in% "z"`, por un grepl("Z",x), verdad?

Comment: Asi es , existe una librería que se llama stringr  simplifica mucho el uso de expresiones regulares, igualmente te comparto un link donde explican muy bien como usar expresiones regulares https://regexr.com/

Comment: Listo. Muchas gracias.